# Passing a specific array element using pointer reference

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I am having problem with passing a pointer by reference.

This is the method

```
void set_range(double **measu)  
{   
if ((*measu)[0] < 0) //or i is used for a loop  
   return ;         
}


int main()
{
   double *mes;
   set_range(&mes[1]);

}
```

I have allocated memory and required values are set. But this program gives me "Unhandled exception Access violation reading location" error. 
So my question is,how to pass the pointer of mes[1] instead of mes[0] (which normally passed when (&mes) is given) to the set_range method?

Comment: It ought to give you a few more errors. You should crank up your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to take a `double*` instead of a `double**`, eg:

```
void set_range(double *measu)
{
  if (*measu < 0) //or i is used for a loop
    return;
}

int main()
{
  double *mes;
  ...
  set_range(&mes[1]);
}
```

Alternatively, use a real reference instead:

```
void set_range(double &measu)
{
  if (measu < 0) //or i is used for a loop
    return;
}

int main()
{
  double *mes;
  ...
  set_range(mes[1]);
}
```

Comment: This question isn't tagged C++ - there are no references in C.

Comment: I changed it to C++. Remy has given what i am expecting (how to pass the pointer of mes[1] instead of mes[0])

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that `&mes[1]` is of type `double *`, not the `double **` required of your function.

Another problem is that `mes` doesn't point to anything - it's uninitialized. So dereferencing it will access junk (which is why you get an access violation).

I'm trying to come up with some code to help clarify, but honestly I have no idea what you're trying to do. Some more code would help us figure out what your goal is, but just given the above I have no idea why you need a `double **` or whether you need dynamic memory or just a single `double` variable.